# Errors When Trying To Update To 1.9.4.1 Using Magento Connect with PHP 7.2

Tags: magento-1.9, upgrade, magento-connect

I am getting errors when attempting to update Mage_All_Latest 1.9.4.1 via Magento Connect Manager

```
CONNECT ERROR: Package community/Mage_All_Latest 1.9.4.1: requires PHP version >= 5.2.0 and <= 6.0.0 current is: 7.2.13
Package community/Interface_Adminhtml_Default 1.9.4.1: requires PHP version >= 5.2.0 and <= 6.0.0 current is: 7.2.13
Package community/Interface_Frontend_Default 1.9.4.1: requires PHP version >= 5.2.0 and <= 6.0.0 current is: 7.2.13
Package community/Interface_Install_Default 1.9.4.1: requires PHP version >= 5.2.0 and <= 6.0.0 current is: 7.2.13
Package community/Mage_Downloader 1.9.4.1: requires PHP version >= 5.2.0 and <= 6.0.0 current is: 7.2.13
Package community/Mage_Centinel 1.9.4.1: requires PHP version >= 5.2.0 and <= 6.0.0 current is: 7.2.13
Package community/Interface_Frontend_Base_Default 1.9.4.1: requires PHP version >= 5.2.0 and <= 6.0.0 current is: 7.2.13
Package community/Phoenix_Moneybookers 1.9.4.1: requires PHP version >= 5.2.0 and <= 6.0.0 current is: 7.2.13
Package community/Mage_Compiler 1.9.4.1: requires PHP version >= 5.2.0 and <= 6.0.0 current is: 7.2.13
Package community/Magento_Mobile 1.9.4.1: requires PHP version >= 5.2.0 and <= 6.0.0 current is: 7.2.13
Package community/Lib_Cm 1.9.4.1: requires PHP version >= 5.2.0 and <= 6.0.0 current is: 7.2.13
Package community/Cm_RedisSession 1.9.4.1: requires PHP version >= 5.2.0 and <= 6.0.0 current is: 7.2.13
Package community/Interface_Frontend_Rwd_Default 1.9.4.1: requires PHP version >= 5.2.0 and <= 6.0.0 current is: 7.2.13
Package community/Mage_Core_Adminhtml 1.9.4.1: requires PHP version >= 5.2.0 and <= 6.0.0 current is: 7.2.13
Package community/Mage_Core_Modules 1.9.4.1: requires PHP version >= 5.2.0 and <= 6.0.0 current is: 7.2.13
Package community/Lib_Js_Ext 1.9.4.1: requires PHP version >= 5.2.0 and <= 6.0.0 current is: 7.2.13
Package community/Lib_LinLibertineFont 2.8.14.18: requires PHP version >= 5.2.0 and <= 6.0.0 current is: 7.2.13
Package community/Lib_Js_TinyMCE 3.5.11.17: requires PHP version >= 5.2.0 and <= 6.0.0 current is: 7.2.13
Package community/Lib_Varien 1.9.4.1 depends on PHP extensions: Array
Package community/Lib_Google_Checkout 1.9.4.1: requires PHP version >= 5.2.0 and <= 6.0.0 current is: 7.2.13
Package community/Lib_Js_Calendar 1.51.1.18: requires PHP version >= 5.2.0 and <= 6.0.0 current is: 7.2.13
Package community/Lib_Js_Mage 1.9.4.1: requires PHP version >= 5.2.0 and <= 6.0.0 current is: 7.2.13
Package community/Lib_Phpseclib 1.9.4.1: requires PHP version >= 5.2.0 and <= 6.0.0 current is: 7.2.13
Package community/Mage_Locale_en_US 1.9.4.1: requires PHP version >= 5.2.0 and <= 6.0.0 current is: 7.2.13
Package community/Lib_Mage 1.9.4.1: requires PHP version >= 5.2.0 and <= 6.0.0 current is: 7.2.13
Package community/Lib_Magento 1.9.4.1: requires PHP version >= 5.2.0 and <= 6.0.0 current is: 7.2.13
Package community/Lib_Credis 1.9.4.1: requires PHP version >= 5.2.0 and <= 6.0.0 current is: 7.2.13
Package community/Lib_Pelago 1.9.4.1: requires PHP version >= 5.2.0 and <= 6.0.0 current is: 7.2.13
Package community/Lib_Unserialize 1.9.4.1: requires PHP version >= 5.2.0 and <= 6.0.0 current is: 7.2.13
Package community/Lib_IDNA2 1.9.4.1: requires PHP version >= 5.2.0 and <= 6.0.0 current is: 7.2.13
Package community/Lib_Mcryptcompat 1.9.4.1: requires PHP version >= 5.2.0 and <= 6.0.0 current is: 7.2.13
Package community/Lib_ZF 1.12.10.17: requires PHP version >= 5.2.0 and <= 6.0.0 current is: 7.2.13
Package community/Lib_Js_Prototype 1.9.4.1: requires PHP version >= 5.2.0 and <= 6.0.0 current is: 7.2.13
Package community/Lib_ZF_Locale 1.12.10.17: requires PHP version >= 5.2.0 and <= 6.0.0 current is: 7.2.13
```

As of 1.9.4.0, Magento is supposed to support PHP 7.2, so why does this update require the older version of PHP?

Can I just change the PHP version locally, update, and push the update to servers running PHP 7.2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to successfully update Magento `1.9.4.0` to `1.9.4.1` using Magento Connect by downgrading PHP to `5.6`, performing the update, and then switching the PHP back to `7.2`.